# Why does "TypeError: 'undefined' object is not callable" come up?

Tags: python

```
subtotal = input("What's the Subtotal?") #input of dinners subtotal
tax_input = input("What's the tax there?") #local tax
tip_input = .20 #average tax is 20%
tax = subtotal * tax_input #tax
tip = subtotal * tip_input #tip
total = subtotal + tax + tip #totalling
print "Your %s was " + tax (tax)
print "Your %s was " + tip (tip)
print "Your %s is " + total (total)
```

What does the error "TypeError: 'undefined' object is not callable" mean? Also, is my code good? I know that instead of using two tax's I can just change the value, but that seems weird to me...

Comment: `print "Your %s was " + tax (tax)` What does that `(tax)` at the end mean? That's what's causing your error.

Comment: The tax in the parentheses is telling the "%s" that the variable tax will be swapped in, or at least that's what I thought, I will also test this! Thanks!

Comment: no you just want `print "Your %s was " % tax`

Comment: see docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: `tax(tax)` tells python "call the `tax` function, passing `tax` as an argument"... which wouldn't make much sense even if `tax` was a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to do something like that?

```
subtotal = input("What's the Subtotal?") #input of dinners subtotal
tax_input = input("What's the tax there?") #local tax
tip_input = .20 #average tax is 20%
tax = subtotal * tax_input #tax
tip = subtotal * tip_input #tip
total = subtotal + tax + tip #totalling
print "Your tax was %s" %tax
print "Your tip was %s" %tip
print "Your total is %s" %total
```

The problem in your code is this

```
print "Your %s was " + tax (tax)
```

`tax` is not a method so you can't call it. Your `tax` is either `int` or `float`, so you need to make it a string to concatenate, either by doing this

```
print "Your tax was %s" %tax
```

or

```
print "Your tax was " + str(tax)
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing your prints as follows should help:

```
print("Your tax was {} ".format(tax))
print("Your tip was {}".format(tip))
print("Your total is {}".format(total))
```

Your code does not work, because tax, tip and total are not functions or callable objects. They just numbers.

Comment: Ok, I will try it, but if I may, why does this fix it? I was thinking of chamging the code below to have str(tax) and etc. would that have helped? Also, just thanks for you answer! :D    print "Your %s was " + tax (tax)
     print "Your %s was " + tip (tip)
     print "Your %s is " + total (total)

Comment: @Hayden Your code does not work, because `tax`, `tip` and `total` are not functions or callable objects. They are just numbers. The format function take cares of formating your number for printing.

Comment: @Hayden if you're not on Python 3 (which I guess maybe not?) you're going to have to `from future import print_function` in your file to use the syntax above. the problem in your code is the bits like `tax (tax)` and `tip (tip)`

Comment: @Anentropic Thanks for you input, I actually do not have Python at the moment (I know, weird right but my internet will not let me download anything) can you please correct my tips and taxs? Thanks for you input!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call tax, tip and total as if they were functions.  They are variables, and not functions.  If you want to replace the strings tax, tip, and total with their respective "titles" you would need to take an approach that uses iterate-able key/value hash (which python conveniently makes easy, but that's for another discussion).

Instead you could simply do something like:

```
`
print "Your tax was", tax
print "Your tip was", tip
print "Your total was", total
`
```

The truth is your code sucks.  So does mine.  It will probably always suck.  Get used to regularly looking back on code you've written before and hating yourself for writing such horrible, wretched code in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for being constructive? I literally learnt all this yesterday in 30 minutes, I didn't expect to be perfect...

Comment: I didn't mean it as an insult.  It was intended in the frame of "don't sweat it, you'll hate it when you look back anyway. Instead, focus on evolving!"